# PDFlib create svg graphic from other image

Tags: php, pdf, svg, pdflib

Is it possible in PDFlib to create an svg graphic from another image-file (like png) and than put it out in the pdf? Like first load the png image with `$p->load_graphics` and than create a svg file within pdflib? I googled this but found nothing that fits my requirement.

For explanation: I have a png graphic and want to create a svg file within my pdflib program, so I can give this image a shadow. Or is it possible to put a shadow on the image through another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create PDF output with PDFlib. If you want to manipulate your SVG in advance you must do so before using load_graphics(). (this is not a functionality of PDFlib)

Please note, however, that PDFlib does not support all possible SVG filters.  Especially `feBlend` and `feGaussianBlur`, which are commonly used for blur shadows, are not supported. (Please refer to chapter 8.2.8 "Unsupported SVG Features" in your or the current [PDFlib tutorial](https://www.pdflib.com/documentation/manuals/) for details.)

Therefore, the more sensible variant is probably to apply an appropriate shadow to the PNG image in advance by image manipulation (eg. by using [ImageMagick](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#shadow)) and load the final PNG to PDFlib.

Comment: thank you for your answer! and it's also not possible to put a shadow on the png with pdflib?

Comment: if you mean a "blur" shadow, then no. If the shadow is just a solid color, then you could paint corresponding areas before placing the image.

Comment: Okay, that is helping me a lot. thanks again!